# map<char*, int> how to use it correctly?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stdstring, stdmap

What is wrong with the code? I wan't to insert five names into a map and maintain a count of all the unique names and finally print. This code crashes after first input is entered. Also tried scanf(). Couldn't debug further!!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<char*, int> VoteCount;
    map<char*, int>::iterator it;
    char* str;
    int i, count;

    for(i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
        cin >> str;
        it = VoteCount.find(str);
        if (it != VoteCount.end()) //if name already present increment the count and insert <name, earlier_count+1>
        {
            count = it->second;
            VoteCount.erase(it);
            VoteCount.insert(pair<char*,int>(str,count+1));

        }
        else //insert the first element <name,count>
        {
            VoteCount.insert(pair<char*,int>(str,1));

        }
    }


    printf("Voting list:\n");
    for (it=VoteCount.begin(); it!=VoteCount.end(); it++)
            cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';


}
```

Comment: is there any reason not to use `string` instead of `char*`?

Comment: Use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is not the OP's yet problem.  The OP's issue right now is they are using `str` and it was never initialized.

Comment: I am a regular C programmer trying out C++. Thats why you may find a char* instead of string.

Comment: Yes, the issue was solved after replacing every occurrence of char* with string. Thanks for the help!!